# How to convert starling.display.MovieClip to flash.display.Movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to convert starling.display.MovieClip to flash.display.Movieclip ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Starling recommends use only its classes instead of native flash controls.

Answer (score 0):

The able to do the opposite

here is an explanation [starlingConverMovieClip](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/flash-movieclip-converter-preserves-display-list-hierarchy)

here is the code [MovieClipConverter](https://github.com/zenrobin/FlashMovieClipConverter)